# R shiny app user upload their own data set and perform analysis

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an R shiny app where users can import their own csv files and perform analysis. I have gotten to the part where they import their data set and it can read it and they select which columns to use using. drop down menu, but I am trying to have a separate tab where there are check boxes for the variables they selected and depending on what is selected in the check box, it creates an ANOVA table for the selected variables. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

I tried creating a function with if else statements like this:

```
create_model <- function(data_input, var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, 
                         var_6, var_7, var_8, var_9, var_10, response_var){
  if(response_var != not_sel && var_1 != not_sel){
  checkboxGroupInput("model_var", "Variables to Include:", choices = c("Variable A", "Response")
   )
    }
```

but this is not working. I also added

```
 ANOVA <- eventReactive(input$run_button, {
    if (input$model_var == "Variable A" && input$model_var == "Response"){
      response <- data_input[,get(response_var)]
      A <- data_input[,get(var_1)]
      anova(response ~ A)
    create_model(data_input(),var_1(), var_2(), var_3(),
               var_4(), var_5(),response_var(),var_6(), var_7(),
               var_8(), var_9(), var_10())
    }
})
  output$ANOVA <- renderTable(ANOVA())
```

in the server section but I am getting an error that says True/false needed

Comment: Does the function work outside of Shiny?